# How can I route from a component to a section of another component in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, routes

I have two components and they are situtated in the different routes. In the Second component There is a div. I want to route from first component to the div of the second component. Yes, It is simple to route the second component. But I want to scroll be top of the div.
[image]

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tag is declared in component1

```
<a [routerLink] = "['/c2']" fragment="c2id"> Link </a>
```

Here are the component2 changes

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-c2',
  templateUrl: './c2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./c2.component.css']
})
export class C2Component implements OnInit {
  private fragment: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
      this.fragment = fragment;
    });
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    try {
      document.querySelector('#' + this.fragment).scrollIntoView();
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

And your component2 html will be like this

```
<p style="height: 800px;">
c2 works!
</p>
<hr>
<div id="c2id" style="height: 500px;">
  The div with c2id
</div>
```

Here is the updated and working stackblitz
https://angular-fragment-example.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Fragments`.

Official Docs : [Angular Docs- Query Params and Fragments](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments)

Examples:

**Manual Navigation**

in `c1.html`

`<a [routerLink] = "['/c2']" [fragment]="c2id"> Link </a>`

in `c2.html`

`<div id="c2id">content</div>`

**Programatic Navigation**

in `c1.ts`

```
private fragmentSetDynamically: string;
constructor(private router: Router){}

onClickButton(){
   this.router.navigate(['/c2'], {fragment: fragmentSetDynamically});
}
```

Getting the fragment :

in `c2.ts`

```
private fragment: string;
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.fragment = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.fragment;
}
```

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: Scroll does not appear the top of the div

Comment: can you replicate your result in stackblitz?

Comment: Yes, I can. Url in the stackblits is following: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afdrkn